# Electron internal css doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, electron

I can´t style my html file with internal css. I would like to use internal because its better then inline. Inline works.

Thats my html file linking.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Tutorial/css/loginStylesheet.css">
```

Thats my stylesheet.

```
html{
background-color: #012C40;
}

body{
margin: 0px;
background-color: #012C40;
}
```

The window works but not the styling.

My Stylesheet is located on the Desktop->Electron->Tutorial/css/loginStylesheet.css

The App I start with "npm star". The normal html file does change but the app dont change the color. If I use inline it change on the app and the web.

Comment: Where is your style-sheet located? (what is it's file path)

Comment: It should work if the path to the file is correct.

Comment: Are you putting style tags around internal css ?

Comment: Are you running this through a server, or just opening the HTML file locally? If you're doing the latter, you'll need a relative rather than absolute URL, i.e.  "./Tutorial/css/loginStylesheet.css"

Comment: /Tutorial/css/loginStylesheet.css

Comment: I edit my post wait pls

Comment: Ok ty VXp, I just read it on stackoverflow but it doesnt help me a lot

Comment: Ok ty its working now. The structure of my folder was wrong. the html file is seperate folder then the css.